# Highcharts: get an event before drilldown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following JS code...

```
data: [
                {
                    name: 'Active',
                    y: 20,

                    events: {
                        //onClick: 
                        click: function (event) {
                            LoadTable(tableData, event);
                        }
                    },
                    drilldown: 'Active'
               }
     ]
```

But the event does not fire up if the drilldown is there... Is that by design? I need to have the drilldown so I can load the Active data on the chart but I need to also call the LoadTable function first...

I tried to put an **alert("test")** but not even that worked....

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the drilldown event.

```
   events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
            alert("drillDown Event");
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/1zLa65Le/)

Comment: It worked great! Thanks a lot! that's exactly what I was looking for :)